# am adding inputs from the form page but the console shows only the email and other elements calls undefined

Tags: html, node.js

```js
const express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
const port = 3000
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get('/', function(req ,res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname +"/singup.html")
})
app.post("/", function(req , res){
    var firstName = req.body.firsName;
    var lastName = req.body.lastName;
    var email = req.body.email;
    console.log(firstName, lastName , email );
    
})


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

```html
  <body class="text-center">
    
<main class="form-signin w-100 m-auto">
 <form action="/" class="form-singin" method="post">
    <img class="mb-4" src="imgs/logo.png" alt="" width="72" height="57">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please sign in</h1>
    <input type="text" name="fName" class="form-control top" placeholder="first name">
    <input type="text" name="lName" class="form-control middle"  placeholder="last name">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control buttom"  placeholder="Email">
    <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign me up</button>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; heersan</p>
  </form>
</main>


    
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
   

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

and this form when I add the First name and last name and email the terminal logs only email and makes first-name and Lastname undefined .it logs on the email not there other elements

Comment: Please don't post code as images! However, the fields in your html are named "fName" and "lName" while you are referring to "firsName" (missing 't' btw) and "secondName" in your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Typo alert !

The attribute names are fName and lName, not firstName/lastName :

```
var firstName = req.body.fName;
var lastName = req.body.lName;
var email = req.body.email;
console.log(firstName, lastName, email );
```

Cheers